# Наложение картинки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Проблемы с наложением картинки на картинку. Мне нужно, чтобы при наведении на картинку добавлялась рамка (вырезал только рамку, формат png): она у меня ложится под картинкой, но никак не сверху нее.

Код HTML:

```
<ul id="history_tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="active by-picture" role="presentation"><a role="tab" href="#year1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controle="year1"><img src="images/photo-staff-1.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="by-picture"><a role="tab" href="#year2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controle="year2"><img src="images/photo-staff-2.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="by-picture"><a role="tab" href="#year3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controle="year3"><img src="images/photo-staff-3.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="by-picture"><a role="tab" href="#year4" data-toggle="tab" aria-controle="year4"><img src="images/photo-staff-4.png" alt=""></a></li>
                </ul>
```

Код CSS:

```
.by-picture{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:10px 0 60px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.by-picture:hover, .by-picture:focus, .by-picture:active{
    background: url(../images/border.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}


.by-picture:hover img, .by-picture:focus img, .by-picture:active img{
    height: 126px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо поставить элементам li и img позиционирование relative или absolute, и li указать z-index : initial, а img z-index: -1.
[Вот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/8s6uchyt/)`

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>

  </div>
</div>

.parent{
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: initial;  
}

.child{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}`
```